# Lacinia-Pedestal GraphQL queries without args

Tags: clojure

I'm using lacinia+pedestal to set up a graphql service, most of the queries I've seen in the tutorial need an arg (iD) e.g. games_by_id, but I'd like to retrieve all objects without an arg:

```
 (defn resolve-all-drivers
  [drivers-map context args value]
  drivers-map)
```

**schema-data.edn**

```
    :all_drivers
  {:type        (list Driver)
   :description "Get all the drivers"
   :resolve     :query/all-drivers}
  }
```

schema:

```
:Driver {:description "A collection of drivers"
        :fields {:id {:type (non-null ID)}
                 :name {:type (non-null String)}
                 :email {:type (non-null String)}}}
```

In GraphiQL:

```
    {
  all_drivers {
    name
  }
}
```

Any idea how I can change this to give me a whole list without args?

Comment: I would find an API very confusing, that gives you "all x" on "x-by-id" with no args.

Comment: I updated the query to return a (list Driver) and created a new query + resolver for it

Answer (score 0):

Updated the resolver map:

```
(defn resolver-map
  [component]
  (let [trips-data (-> (io/resource "trips-data.edn")
                       slurp
                       edn/read-string)
        trips-map (entity-map trips-data :trips)
        cars-map (entity-map trips-data :cars)
        drivers-map (get trips-data :drivers)]
    {:query/trip-by-id (partial resolve-trip-by-id trips-map)
     :query/drivers-by-id (partial resolve-drivers-by-id drivers-map)
     :query/all-drivers (partial resolve-all-drivers drivers-map)
     :Trip/cars (partial resolve-trip-cars cars-map)
     :Car/trips (partial resolve-car-trips trips-map)}))
```